# Form submitting from another router in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a newbie in React and I'm trying to make a basic meal app. In App component, I'm searching for meal and fetching data from my api and clicking on any meal for its detail page. However, on detail page when searching a new meal it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for your answer in advance.

It's my App.js

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/Header'
import Search from './components/Search'
import MealList from './components/MealList'
import MealDetail from './components/MealDetail'

import axios from 'axios';
import styles from './App.module.css';

function App(props) {

  const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(true);

  console.log(props)


  const getQuery = (query) => {

    //history.replace('/');
    setIsLoaded(false);
    axios.get(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${query}`)
    .then(response => {
      setIsLoaded(true);
      setMeals(response.data.meals)
    })

  }
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className={styles.body}>
      <Header />
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <Search getQuery={getQuery} />
        <Route path='/' exact render={() => <MealList meals={meals} />} />
        <Route path='/meals/:id' component={MealDetail} />
      </div>


    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with "withRouter" in App component. It gave me some information with props and I redirected to the homepage when form submitting.